# Bucle infinito en relacion @ManyToOne en Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring, jpa, relaciones

Tengo dos entidades: Pais y provincia, con sus datos en una base de datos, la relacion que tienen es mediante la anotacion @OneToMany y @ManyToOne respectivamente, al consultar los datos con **Postman** la lista de paises se muestra bien, y en el caso de Argentina muestra las provincias que estan relacionadas. Al momento de querer ver las provincias, las cuales se realcionan con Pais mediante id_pais, postman me da error y si hago la consulta en google chrome, me trae un ciclo infinito cuando dejo el metodo getPais() de la entidad Provincia. Pero si comento dicho metodo, puedo ver los datos de las provincias, pero no puedo ver el pais al que pertenece cada una de las provincias.

La entidad Pais es la siguiente:

```
@Entity
public class Pais {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String nombre;
    private String nacionalidad;
    private String codigo;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "pais", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    List<Provincia> provincia;

    public Pais() {
    }

    public Pais(String nombre, String nacionalidad, String codigo) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.nacionalidad = nacionalidad;
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }
```

Mientras que la Entidad Provincia es la siguiente:

```
@Entity
public class Provincia {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String nombre;
    private String gentilicio;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_pais")
    Pais pais;

    public Provincia() {
    }

    public Provincia(String nombre, String gentilicio) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.gentilicio = gentilicio;
    }
```

Ambas entidades tienen sus importaciones correspondientes y sus getters y setters.

Answer (score 1):

Para evitar ciclos infinitos al serializar las entidades a formato JSON (por ejemplo, al devolverlas como respuestas en un controlador REST), puedes utilizar la anotación @JsonIgnore en los lugares adecuados. Por ejemplo, puedes agregarla en la propiedad provincias de la entidad Pais o en la propiedad pais de la entidad Provincia, dependiendo de tus necesidades.

```
// En la entidad Pais
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "pais", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JsonIgnore
List<Provincia> provincias = new ArrayList<>();
```

ó

```
// En la entidad Provincia
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "id_pais")
@JsonIgnore
Pais pais;
```

Esto evitará que Jackson intente serializar las propiedades marcadas con @JsonIgnore, evitando así ciclos infinitos.

Comment: Gracias, funciona muy bien!! pero, entonces no hay manera e poder ver una sola vez el pais cuano hago el llamao a la provincia, sin entrar en el bucle infinito?